# Error term of the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

It is known that if $(a, q)$ and $q\le (\ln x)^N$, then the following is true

$$\sum_{k\le x, k\equiv a\pmod{q}}\Lambda(k) = \frac{x}{\phi(q)} + O(x\exp(-C\sqrt{\ln x}))$$

where $C$ depends only on $N$. This error term appears because of the possibility of a counterexample to the Generalised Riemann Hypothesis. What would the error term be if the GRH was true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corollary 13.8 of Montgomery and Vaughn's Multiplicative Number Theory states that under the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis for the Dirichlet $L$ functions of characters $\chi$ modulo $q$, we have that $$\psi(x;q,a)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
n\leq x\\
n\equiv a\ (q)
\end{array}}\Lambda(n)=\frac{x}{\phi(q)}+O\left(x^{1/2}\log^{2}x\right).$$ In particular, if GRH is true, then we have the asymptotic $\psi(x;q,a)\sim\frac{x}{\phi(q)}$ for all $q\leq x^{1/2}/\log^3(x)$.